# Word for "openness"/"closedness" of an interval

Tags: terminology, definition

What word properly completes the phrase

> the radius of convergence does not depend on the $\text{______}$ of the interval

to mean that it doesn't matter whether $(a, b)$, $[a, b)$, $(a, b]$, or $[a, b]$ is the correct answer?

- *Openness* and *closedness* don't really seem to work because the interval doesn't have to be either (it could be half-open, or, in $\mathbb{R}^n$, include any subset of its limit points).
- *Strictness* makes sense, because you can say that $2$, and not $3$, is "strictly between" $1$ and $3$. However, this only really makes sense (to me) once you know the meaning; if I saw the word *strictness* I wouldn't really know what it meant.
- *Boundary* and *endpoints* don't work because the boundary does matter—we care what $a$ and $b$ are, just not whether they're included in the interval.

This is for a Calculus II class, so *topology*, etc. are outside the scope of the curriculum.

Thoughts?

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick I don't think that works because it seems to imply that we don't care what $a$ and $b$ are.

Comment: Maybe "half-open/closedness" then?

Comment: "Half-open/closedness" is close but a bit too specific to $\mathbb{R}^1$. This is for a Calculus II class, so "topology" wouldn't be understandable.

Comment: What's wrong with being specific to $\Bbb R^1$? The notion of "interval" isn't really meaningful in any other space.

Comment: Right, but "interval" is a special case of "ball," and you could have a ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that contains some but not all of its limit points. It wouldn't really be "half-open" or "half-closed," but it wouldn't be either open or closed, either. $$ $$ There's nothing *wrong* with being specific to $\mathbb{R}^1$ in this context. I'm just wondering if there's a better way to communicate this.

Comment: Yes but your context is the interval of convergence of a power series. There's no reason to consider anything other than $\Bbb R^1$.

Comment: I might use the word 'type', or I would just rewrite the sentence (the radius of convergence does not depend on whether the interval includes the endpoints or not).

Comment: @AlexZorn ah—that's much better to rewrite the sentence. Good call.

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

> the radius of convergence does not depend on the nature of the interval, i.e.,whether it is closed, open, or neither.

Answer (score 0):

"The radius of convergence does not depend on whether the interval is open, closed, or neither."